# Error while switching window in python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to work with multiple windows and tabs using selenium and python.

I am getting below error during script execution:- 
( code is mentioned at last)

```
{f625f26d-cfcf-442c-b9fc-5e96a199cd43}
C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.47.1- py3.4.egg\selenium\webdriver\remot
e\webdriver.py:525: DeprecationWarning: use driver.switch_to.window instead
 warnings.warn("use driver.switch_to.window instead", DeprecationWarning)
 {cad6e3cf-9062-408e-a6f1-11e98813dc6c}
```

---

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

class GoogleTabs(unittest.TestCase):

 def setUp(self):
     self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

 def test_google_search_page(self):
     driver = self.driver
     driver.get("http://www.cdot.in")
     window_before = driver.window_handles[0]
     print (window_before)
     driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@href='http://www.cdot.in/home.htm']").click()
     window_after = driver.window_handles[1]
     driver.switch_to_window(window_after)
     print (window_after)
     driver.find_element_by_link_text("ATM").click()
     driver.switch_to_window(window_before)


 def tearDown(self):
     self.driver.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
unittest.main()
```

Comment: Is it an error or a warning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting a warning message, for new versions of selenium the method has changed.

Instead of using: `driver.switch_to_window(window)`

Try with: `driver.switch_to.window`

Where `window` is your variable.

Answer (score 3):

As the warning says

> DeprecationWarning: use driver.switch_to.window instead

you'll need to change your

```
driver.switch_to_window
```

with

```
driver.switch_to.window
```

But think about it: it is a warning, not an error! Your code should work, it is just telling you that that method is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

I propose a very simple way to switch between windows without any hassles of playing with the handles yourself. https://gist.github.com/ab9-er/08c3ce7d2d5cdfa94bc7

```
def change_window(browser):
    """
    Simple window switcher without the need of playing with ids.
    @param browser: Current browser instance
    """
    curr = browser.current_window_handle
    all_handles = browser.window_handles
    for handle in list(set([curr]) - set(all_handles)):
        return browser.switch_to_window(handle)
```